# How to display console result on a Web Server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Please forgive me if this question may not fit this site. I have recently installed Pure-FTPd service running on CentOS. To view current connects, I run the command **pure-ftpwho**, below is the screen output:

```
+------+---------+-------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| PID  |  Login  |For/Spd| What |                 File/IP                   |
+------+---------+-------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| 7233 | login001| 00:00 | IDLE | ->     xxx-xx-xx-xxx.mydomain.com         |
|  ''  |    ''   |   ''  |  ''  |                                           |
+------+---------+-------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| 7532 | login002| 00:05 | IDLE | ->                 xxxxxx.xxxxx.com       |
|  ''  |    ''   |   ''  |  ''  |                                           |
+------+---------+-------+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

or **pure-ftpwho -s**

```
7233|login001|56|IDLE||xxx-xx-xx-xxx.mydomain.com|ftpserver1|21|0|0|0|0
7532|login002|338|IDLE||xxxxxx.xxxxx.com|ftpserver1|21|0|0|0|0
```

I have another server running Apache Web Service and I am thinking of creating an html or php page that will display the same result for my end users.

I just need a little bit of guide on how I can approach this either using php, javascript, or JQuery.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could start by looking into http://php.net/system and http://php.net/exec and http://php.net/passthru

However, if you really do not need a real real-time output, the best approach might be that you actually run this command in a scheduled job (cron?), every minute or so, and redirect it's output to text file, which you later pass in php.

For example, every minute you run `pure-ftpwho -s > /var/www/who` and then get the file contents with `<? $who = file_get_contents("/var/www/who"); ?>` in PHP.

Let me know if something like this works for you.

Comment: Hi Kasipovic, I actually thought about running a cron job on the FTP server as suggested, the bit I wasn't so good at was how to pass the text output from the web server. Let me try this and i will paste my code

Comment: You do not need to pass it to web server, pass it to a local file, which you will then read from a script (PHP for example)